# filebeat -.> logstash proxy

Tags: logstash, filebeat

So, my situation:

Host1 in network 1 - filebeat. HostP in network P (proxy) - filebeat. HostL in NetwokL - Logstash. And host ES in network ES, Elasticsearch.

Host1 has access only to HostP, no access further than that. HostP has access to HostL.

What i want: to ship logs from Host1 all the way to ES.

The chain HostP to ES works ok, no problems. My logs from HostP arrive quite ok in ES.

So, how do i proxy/chain/feed my logs from Host1 to HostL??? Preferably without installing logstash on HostP since it's jvm and eats quite a bit of resources?

Tried with microsocks and works quite ok but it's a regular proxy software, not reverse, and i don't want other hosts from Network1 to access anything else in NetworkP. Installing a firewall is not an option.

Best would be to have filebeat on HostP forward the messages from Host1 to HostL - if that's even possible,

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are your hosts using? Assuming they are Linux based, you can install HAProxy (or NGINX) in your `HOST P` and configure only the frontend to receive data from your `HOST 1` with the backend to ship data to your `HOST L`.

Comment: True but i want something that's light and doesn't use too many resources and has a basic config. I might try redir.

SO far i managed to have the logs from Host1 shipped to ES using logbeat as a relay but HostP adds it's own headers and encompasses the whole JSON from HOST 1 in it's own message field. Plus it add some 6 gibberish characters at the start of the message string. If i could could at least remove those gibberish characters i could maybe transform the payload in something useful ...